# Different logs: local VS docker (local) vs docker SWARM

Tags: python, docker, logging

I log some info in my app after some specific steps and those are the results in 3 different environment:

```
LOCAL
[2020-07-31 08:38:46 -0400] [4810] [INFO] validation
[2020-07-31 08:38:51 -0400] [4810] [INFO] valid

DOCKER LOCAL
[2020-07-30 20:38:55 +0000] [8] [INFO] validation
INFO:app.main:validation
[2020-07-30 20:38:59 +0000] [8] [INFO] valid
INFO:app.main:valid

DOCKER SWARM
[2020-07-27 14:13:08 +0000] [9] [INFO] validation
INFO:app.main:validation
[2020-07-27 14:13:08 +0000] [9] [INFO] valid
INFO:app.main:valid
[2020-07-27 14:13:09 +0000] [9] [INFO] validation
INFO:app.main:validation
[2020-07-27 14:13:09 +0000] [9] [INFO] valid
INFO:app.main:valid
```

As you can see, when I run the app in local env it logs correctly but when in Docker it duplicates everything.

What is the deal from Docker env?

Comment: Did you change the default logging driver? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

Comment: And how you got this logs? `docker log ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the format of the extra messages e.g. `INFO:app.main:validation` it looks as if something is calling `logging.basicConfig()` in the Docker environment. This might be either explicitly, or implicitly via a call to e.g. `logging.info()` or similar. Here's an example using the REPL:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
>>> logging.getLogger('app.main').info('validation')
INFO:app.main:validation
>>>
```

So, look for a call in your code like `logging.info()` or a call to `logging.basicConfig()` which would only occur when Dockerized.